# Transferring site to an ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, shared-hosting, transfer

I am attempting to transfer a website from a bluehost server to an AWS ubuntu 16.04 server. I have moved ~12 sites to the new server without any problems. one site in particular won't transfer properly. This site is adental.ca.

[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpDnu.jpg)

This link shows how the site should look

This link shows how the site currently looks

[Broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaBam.png)

Methods I've tried to transfer it are as follows
1.Through the WP all in one plugin
2.Importing the site through Filezilla FTP, and uploading the database.
3.Running a backup on all in one plugin, downloading the file, and uploading the file through ftp. Then restoring.
4.downloading the files through the bluehost portal and uploading them onto the new site.

I believe the files may be being corrupted as they are being pulled off the bluehost server, But I had the site working for ~1 day. It worked on several computers so it wasn't just the fact that the site was cached. But it reverted back to being broken after the day. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: The issue was an activated plugin that had a set path that it drew files from. When the site was transferred, this set path had moved. The issue was resolved by getting rid of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was an activated plugin that had a set path that it drew files from. When the site was transferred, this set path had moved. The issue was resolved by getting rid of the plugin.